# Matlab Read Text File List Exclude first 34 characters

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read values from a text file. I want the value after ': '.

Here is a sample of the text file. All lines are formated the same.
There are 34 places before the start of the data.

```
File Name                       : IMG_1184.JPG
File Size                       : 2.1 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2012:07:14 11:53:18-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
```

I tried to use this code:

```
fileID = fopen('Exif.txt');
Exif1 = textscan(fileID, '%s %s','delimiter', ':');
```

This worked on most of the data but some data also used ':' so that didn't work.

I tried to use this code:

```
fileID = fopen('Exif.txt');
Exif1 = textscan(fileID, '%s %s','delimiter', ': ');
```

This returned a mess. Not sure why. Everything was fragmented.

Can anyone explain how to just get the 35th value to the end of every string and put it into an array?

Answer (score 0):

There is the function `strtrim(string)` in Matlab which will strip the leading and trailing spaces for you. Try reading the data in a line at the time into the `textscan` function after using `strtrim`?

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole line into a variable then get the 35th and subsequent characters like this:

```
whole_line(35:end)
```